# mass terminal control

Tags: ssh, tty

I have 1000x Ubuntu 16 containers running in docker for stress testing a piece of software we are testing.

I can ssh into each of these boxes one at a time ... but I am looking for a way of automating the command and control of this internal botnet.  Is there a tool for command line mirroring? Like type the command `sudo shutdown -r now` or `sudo service myService restart` and get a response from all 1000x terminals ... even if it was just a return code for the command?

so far I have looked into:

- expect scripts
- puppet / chef
- writing my own based on [wetty](https://github.com/krishnasrinivas/wetty)

Comment: ansible is a good option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[pssh](https://code.google.com/archive/p/parallel-ssh/)

PSSH provides parallel versions of OpenSSH and related tools. Included are pssh, pscp, prsync, pnuke, and pslurp. The project includes psshlib which can be used within custom applications. The source code is written in Python and can be cloned from:

git clone http://code.google.com/p/parallel-ssh/

PSSH is supported on Python 2.4 and greater (including Python 3.1 and greater). It was originally written and maintained by Brent N. Chun. Due to his busy schedule, Brent handed over maintenance to Andrew McNabb in October 2009.

```
Usage: pssh [OPTIONS] command [...]

Options:
  --version             show program's version number and exit
  --help                show this help message and exit
  -h HOST_FILE, --hosts=HOST_FILE
                        hosts file (each line "[user@]host[:port]")
  -H HOST_STRING, --host=HOST_STRING
                        additional host entries ("[user@]host[:port]")
  -l USER, --user=USER  username (OPTIONAL)
  -p PAR, --par=PAR     max number of parallel threads (OPTIONAL)
  -o OUTDIR, --outdir=OUTDIR
                        output directory for stdout files (OPTIONAL)
  -e ERRDIR, --errdir=ERRDIR
                        output directory for stderr files (OPTIONAL)
  -t TIMEOUT, --timeout=TIMEOUT
                        timeout (secs) (0 = no timeout) per host (OPTIONAL)
  -O OPTION, --option=OPTION
                        SSH option (OPTIONAL)
  -v, --verbose         turn on warning and diagnostic messages (OPTIONAL)
  -A, --askpass         Ask for a password (OPTIONAL)
  -x ARGS, --extra-args=ARGS
                        Extra command-line arguments, with processing for
                        spaces, quotes, and backslashes
  -X ARG, --extra-arg=ARG
                        Extra command-line argument
  -i, --inline          inline aggregated output and error for each server
  --inline-stdout       inline standard output for each server
  -I, --send-input      read from standard input and send as input to ssh
  -P, --print           print output as we get it
```

https://code.google.com/archive/p/parallel-ssh/

example usage:

```
 pssh -i -h hosts.txt echo "hello, world"
```

Comment: This didnt age well ... the correct solution is to use ansible or salt.